# Bypass error and simply show the entered text for number_format argument

Tags: php

I'm aware that [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) requires a number as first argument.
I have a form with many input text fields which require numbers as answers and outputs the numbers formatted using number_format.
But if the user enters text, the output throws an error.
`Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in /path/to/file/script.php on line 519`
Is there any way to bypass this error and simply show the text if the user has entered one ?

Comment: Why not just type check? `if (is_numeric($input)) { echo number_format($input) } else { echo $input }`

Comment: There are about 35 such lines. Can't this be caught using a single try catch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has an [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) class that is used when you want to convert errors to exceptions. The same page shows how:

```
function exception_error_handler($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $severity)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting
        return;
    }
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $file, $line);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

try {
   // Normal code that raises errors 
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
    //Handle it
}

restore_error_handler();
```

Specific alternative to your case:

```
function numberFormatOrDefault($number , $decimals = 0 , $dec_point = "." ,  $thousands_sep = ",") {
    if (is_numeric($number)) {
        return number_format($number, $decimals, $dec_point, $thousands_sep); 
    } else {
        return $number;
    }
}

$str1 = "123.2";
$str2 = "not a number";
echo numberFormatOrDefault($str1,4); //123.2000
echo numberFormatOrDefault($str2);   //not a number
```

Then you can replace your `number_format` calls with the `numberFormatOrDefault` calls (just a simple find and replace will work).

I prefer the second on because it fixes the specific problem instead of catching every single PHP error that may occur as it is not an ideal way to solve  this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below user defined function

```
function foo($val)
{
    if (is_numeric($val)) 
    { 
       echo number_format($val);
    } 
   else 
   { 
     echo $val; 
   }
}
```

And call this where ever required

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 input type number to restrict only number entries:

input type="number" name="textname"

This will work only in HTML5 complaint browser. Make sure your html document's doctype is: !DOCTYPE html

Comment: You can also use the pattern attribute in html5:

<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[0-9]" title="Title" />